# Why my zsh has blank line on bottom?

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

When I use tmux at my terminal, my zsh show blank line on bottom.
I can't find any wrong with my zshrc . 
Can anybody help me solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User or, in this case, https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/250547/104123 (change the font size/type)